# Finding the values of real constants to satisfy an expression on limit at infinity

Tags: calculus, limits

Find the values of real constants $a$ and $b$ such that $\lim_{x\to\infty} (\sqrt{ax^2+1} -\sqrt{x^2+bx}) = 2021$

I'm not sure how to start, I've considered separating the expression and finding $\lim_{x\to\infty} \sqrt{ax^2+1}$ first but I don't know how to cancel out the $x$ valued at infinity. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**
$$
\sqrt{ax^2+1} -\sqrt{x^2+bx}=\left(\sqrt{ax^2+1} -\sqrt{x^2+bx}\right)\frac{\sqrt{ax^2+1} +\sqrt{x^2+bx}}{\sqrt{ax^2+1} +\sqrt{x^2+bx}}\\
=\frac{\left(a-1\right)x^2-bx+1}{\sqrt{ax^2+1} +\sqrt{x^2+bx}}
$$
It is a useful trick when you deal with difference of square roots.

Do you know how to evaluate this kind of limit now that it is a quotient ?

**Edit :**

Replying to @Sukhoi234 :

Let's analyze
$$
\frac{\left(a-1\right)x^2-bx+1}{\sqrt{ax^2+1} +\sqrt{x^2+bx}}
$$

you see that the limit goes to $\pm \infty$ iif $a \ne 1$ because the degree of the numerator is more than the denominator and it is necessary to make the $x^2$ vanish. Hence $a=1$. The expression is hence
$$
\frac{-bx+1}{\sqrt{x^2+1} +\sqrt{x^2+bx}}\underset{(+\infty)}{\sim}\frac{-b}{2}
$$
Hence you need to choose $b=-4042$

Comment: Please can you post the compete answer ? I am not the OP , but I am also not able to solve this .

Comment: @Sukhoi234 See the edit

Comment: Thank you very much !!

Answer (score 0):

$$L=\lim_{x\to \infty}[\sqrt{ax^2+1}-\sqrt{x^2+1}]=\lim_{x\to \infty} x\sqrt{a}\left(1+\frac{1}{ax^2}\right)^{1/2}-x\left(1-\frac{b}{x}\right)^{1/2}$$
Use $\lim_{z\to 0} (1+z)^{k}=1+kz+O(z^2).$
Then $$L=\lim_{x\to \infty} x\sqrt{a}\left(1+\frac{1}{2ax^2}\right)-x\left(1+\frac{b}{2x}\right)=\lim_{x\to \infty} x\sqrt{a}-x+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{a}x}-\frac{b}{2}=2021$$
$$\implies a=1, b=-4042$$